# How to mimick the 7zip "extract to "."" context menu option from Windows

Tags: extract

I'm pretty new at using the terminal and was wondering how to place a folder full of .zip files into sub folders named the same as the .zip file it was extracted from.

So far I figured that `unzip '*.zip' -d` will extract all the .zip files into a single directory, but I'm not sure how to point/create destination folders for the `-d` for each .zip file.

Alternatively, the Nautilus Action Config Tool seems like if might be able to mimic the 7zip Extract To command, but this seems a bit more daunting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `Nautilus Action Config Tool` option and calling my `script zippy.sh`:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
# Unzipping and organizing files from nautilus
m=0 # counter
while [ -n "$1" ] && [ -f "$1" ]
do
    if [[ "$1" =~ \.zip$ ]]
    then
        dir="$1"
        dir=${dir%.*}
        unzip "$1" -d "$dir"
        m=$(($m + 1))
        shift
    fi
done
zenity --info --text="Operations finished and "$m" zip files unzipped"
exit 0
```

1. Place script here:

   ```
   ~/.local/share/nautilus/scripts/
   ```
2. Make it executable with `chmod +x ~/.local/share/nautilus/scripts/zippy.sh`

Explained:

1. `-n` and `-f` check file number is not zero and is file respectively
2. `=~ \.zip$` make sure it's a zip file
3. `${dir%.*}` cut off the `zip` part of filename
4. `m=$(($m + 1))` count how many zip files are worked on.
5. `shift` flip through files
6. `zenity` display a message box to indicate operations conclusion

Comment: Great! I will definitely try that out. And I had to edit my previous code as I just got luck with the files extracting to the correct folders on my test run.

Comment: No problemo, first time on, didn't notice the check mark.

Answer (score 1):

I edited a script that I found for file name to folder name to extract into the created folder.

Revised:
In your directory create a file with:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
find . -type f ! -name "*exto*" | while read file;
do
    f=$(basename "$file")
    f1=${f%.zip}
    mkdir "$f1"
    unzip "$f" -d "$f1" 
done
```

In terminal:

```
chmod +x exto
./exto
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also just download the 7Zip version for linux. https://sourceforge.net/projects/p7zip/files/
It is called p7zip

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/6e6f6d1b-95c3-46df-8a26-b7efd8ee4b57/entry/how_to_use_7zip_on_linux_command_line144?lang=en
This also provides a very detailed guide of installation and use

Comment: I did, but it didn't add anything to the context menu nor did I find a command that would create folders from the file names from the archlinux wiki [link](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/p7zip)

Comment: Have you tried this https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/6e6f6d1b-95c3-46df-8a26-b7efd8ee4b57/entry/how_to_use_7zip_on_linux_command_line144?lang=en